# Why can symbol in eval not be resolved?

Tags: clojure

Why does

```
((fn[x] (eval (symbol "x"))) 1)
```

blow up `Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context`?

I expected it to behave just like

```
((fn[x] x) 1)
```

and evaluate to `1`.

(How) Can the former be fixed to return `1` using `eval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` does not use the lexical scope where it is called (as introduced by `fn`, `let`, or `loop`), it only sees vars as mapped via the current namespace (bound to the var `*ns*`).

Introducing a lexical binding into an eval context will involve wrapping the form in a `let` manually, or using undocumented implementation dependent host interop to find and provide lexical bindings to the eval context.

An example of wrapping in a let manually (this will only work when `x` is something readable by the Clojure reader):

```
user=> (def x 0)
#'user/x
user=> (let [x 42] (eval 'x)) ; gets the global value of x, not local
0
user=> (let [x 42] (eval (list 'let ['x (list 'quote x)] 'x))) ; manually getting the local
42
```

Comment: ... hence, for example, `(def x 3) ((fn[x] (eval (symbol "x"))) 1)` produces `3`, not `1`.

Comment: Obscure, undocumented hacks aside. I don't quite get what you mean by "wrapping in a let manually". I may be missing something but to me it seems there is really no way to access lexical scope from eval.

Comment: I mean constructing a let block that contains the local value. `(eval (list 'let ['x x] 'x)`

Comment: edited the answer to give a more concrete example of what I meant

Comment: The last example  works with `42`. Try `(Object.)`. :)